# pip does not list all the installed packages when I do a pip list

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I installed elastalert2 packages via pip3 in a python venv using the below commands
`pip3 install elastalert2`

The install went through fine, however I do not see it in the list of packages. I am using the below commands
`pip list`
`pip3 list`
`pip freeze --all`

i expect all the installed packages to show up when i do `pip list`. Any help here will be appreciated

Comment: `pip3` and `pip` are two different commands. They may (and often do) refer to different Python interpreters.

Comment: Is the venv activated? What happens when you do `which pip` and `which pip3`?